# QR codes image generator in java (open source but no GPL)

Tags: java, encode, qr-code

I'm seeking an open source QR codes image generator component in java (J2SE), but the open source licence mustn't be a GPL licence (needs to be included in a close source project).

BTW, i can't access the web from the project so no Google API.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Mercer - no, there is an encoder in the library too. com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder. We provide that in addition to an example web app using Google Chart APIs

Comment: ok thank you! i just have to create an Image using the qrCode.getMatrix().getArray();

Comment: In case anyone else is doing this, heres the basic idea. Use Encoder.encode() to 'fill-in' the details of a newly instantiated QRCode. Then get the byte[][] from QRCode.getMatrix().getArray() as suggested above. Each line of bytes seems to be a row of pixels for the QRCode, with each byte being zero or one. At this point you could just paint the pixels to a BufferedImage or make a Raster out of it or something to turn it into an AWT image.

Comment: ... or use the provided class MatrixToImageWriter to do all this for you !

Answer (score 14):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java.
It is released under the *The Apache License*, so it allows use of the source code for the development of proprietary software as well as free and open source software.

Comment: Doesn't generate QR Codes. It only scans them.

Comment: In their web app example of qr generator they are using http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html#qrcodes to generate the qr code.

Comment: I can't access the web from the project so, no google API or web service.

Comment: They do, however, have an almost finished implementation of the qr code generator - not the qr image generator. So you could give this project a try.

Comment: The generator i saw, in that project is the one using GWT, or did i missed something ?

Comment: No the project has both a GWT front-end for QR Code generation that uses the Google Chart Server for the actual image generation, and also a native Java QR Code generator that can be embedded.

Answer (score 2):

MatrixToImageWriter uses BitMatrix, not ByteMatrix as returned by QRCode.getMatrix. by looking at android sourcecode, I found the following proof of concept solution:

```
    try {
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();    
        Hashtable hints = new Hashtable();
        hints.put( EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.Q );            
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToFile( writer.encode( "hello world", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 800, 800, hints ),
                                         "png", new File( "/tmp/qrcode.png" ) );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println( "failure: " + e );
    }
```

btw imposing Hashtable in API is not clean. please use Map. not many people still use Hashtable anyway, you should almost always use HashMap instead (except a few use cases).

Comment: Responding to this very old comment I just saw: it used `Hashtable` for compatibility with J2ME, which does not have `Map`. But since v2.0 J2ME support was dropped and the API takes a `Map`.