# How to Create QRCode using Java (J2SE)

Tags: java, qr-code

How to create QRcode image using normal j2se. Any APIs or classes are available to do this?

Comment: (didn't you ask for normal j2se? Thought, you already did a search for "java create QRCode" ...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137415/qr-codes-image-generator-in-java-open-source-but-no-gpl

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To do this you need to download following jars,

- zxing-core-1.7.jar
- zxing-javase-1.7.jar

from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

try the following code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from("Hello World").to(ImageType.PNG).stream();

try {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\QR_Code.JPG"));

    fout.write(out.toByteArray());

    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Do Logging
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Do Logging
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried to use your code, I've includes java2se.jar and core.jar from zxing. But I'm getting errors at `QRCode.from() - cannot find symbol from(java.lang.String)` and `ImageType.PNG`. What could be the possible problem??

Comment: This is possibly because of package imports error. try this              import net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode;
import net.glxn.qrgen.image.ImageType;

Comment: Where can I find the libraries for the `net.glxn.qrgen.QRCode` and `net.glxn.qrgen.image.ImageType` my current import is `import com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.QRCode;`

Comment: You can find here   https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen/blob/master/dist/qrgen-1.0.jar           total three jars you need             1. qrgen-1.0.jar 2.zxing-core-1.7.jar 3.zxing-j2se-1.7.jar