# How to set the error correction level of a QRC using QRGen?

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing, error-correction

I have the project from below working on my system:

[How to Create QRCode using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257063/867591)

But I'm unable to figure how to set the error correction level using this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [QRGen documentation](http://kenglxn.github.com/QRGen/javadocs/index.html), you can't.

This lib a convenient wrapper around ZXing to make it easier to create simple QRCodes, but if you want to do more complicated things such as specifying the error correction level, you'll have to use ZXing directly.

Comment: Thanks...I guess it is back to the drawing board for me :)

Comment: 2.0-SNAPSHOT should solve this https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/glxn/qrgen/android/2.0-SNAPSHOT/

https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen