# Opensource API for generate QR code

Tags: java, barcode

I want to generate Bulk of QR codes for random set of codes. Please help me to choose best open source Java API for do this?

Comment: This question does not very well fit the Q&A format on StackOverflow (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) ) and is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137415/qr-codes-image-generator-in-java-open-source-but-no-gpl. To get good answers, it is best to provide some source code of what you have tried and describe what does not work as you expected.

Comment: The Explanations and Example code of the site will help to you.http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-qr-codes-java-servlet-qr-code-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the [barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/) library, it offers image objects, which can be drawn with Swing/AWT and supports export to PNG, GIF and JPEG.